# First-Order Stochastic Dominance

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions, economics

Consider two cumulative distribution functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$ where $G(x)$ has the first-order stochastic dominance over $F(x)$. That is, $F(x)>G(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. We assume $a<0$ and $b>0$. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the probability density function of $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ respectively.

Suppose the expected value of $x$ under $F(x)$ is positive:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx=\int_{a}^{0}xf(x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}xf(x)dx>0.
$$

Under this condition, does $f(x)-g(x)>0$ always hold in any interval of $0<x<b$?

[Graphical Expression of the Question is Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Qlf.png)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Could you tell me how I can edit my question? Should I delete this question and post a new question?

Comment: Please don't delete the question. There is a link that allows you to edit the question just below it. (It is just above and to the left of the box that shows your name.)

Comment: Also, your definition of FOSD seems much stronger than [the usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order). Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:**

Suppose $a=-1$ and $b=2$, that $F$ is the uniform distribution in the interval $[-1,2]$, and that $G$ is the uniform distribution in the interval $[0,2]$. Clearly the expected value of $x$ under $F$ is positive but $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}=f(x)\quad\text{for all}\;x\in[0,b].$$